# How to get multiple variation of product from 2 click with same level?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the website with the product set which have 2 color and 6 variations -> total 12 products. How can I get all information while 'color' click same level with 'variation' click ?! Thank you very much

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time, re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
PATH = "C:/Users/aston/Documents/playground_python/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
test_url = 'https://moho.com.vn/products/bo-ban-an-go-cao-su-tu-nhien-moho-vline-601'  
test = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(test_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
btn_count = []
for btn_cnt in test.select('.select-swap > div'):
    btn_cnt = btn_cnt['data-value'].count('class')
    btn_count.append(btn_cnt)
vari = len(btn_count)
xpath = []
for b in range(1,vari):
    btn_path = '''//div[@class="select-swatch clearfix"]/div/div/div[''' + str(b) + ''']/label'''
    print(btn_path)
    xpath.append(btn_path)
xpath.remove('//div[@class="select-swatch clearfix"]/div/div/div[7]/label')
for i in xpath:
    driver.get('https://moho.com.vn/products/bo-ban-an-go-cao-su-tu-nhien-moho-vline-601')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).click() 
    time.sleep(1)
    sku = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@id="pro_sku"]').text
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="pro-price"]').text
    print({"sku": "price"})
```

Firstly, I count and get all the xpath all 12 variations of the set products. Secondly, by each xpath, I get  sku and price of each product.
At the moment I only get df like this: {SKU: MFDTSVLBR2.N16: 6,590,000₫, SKU: MFDTSVLDC4.B16: 7,390,000₫, SKU: MFDTSVLBR1DC2.N16: 7,190,000₫, SKU: MFDTSVLBR2.N16: 6,590,000₫, SKU: MFDTSVLBD2.N16: 5,790,000₫, SKU: MFDTSVLBR1DB1.N16: 6,190,000₫}. The df are missing 1 variation of product set with natural color (SKU: MFDTSVLDC4.N16:7,390,000₫) and 5 variations of product set with brown color.
I want to know how to write a coding for 'xpath' which will select 2 conditions (one for color and two for variations of set)

Comment: Can you explain more about the query. What is expected output, what are you able to achieve till now?

Comment: The hardest part I met that is the website have 2 select button with same indent. I have created many xpath to click on 2 this button and get product data but it won't work ('''/div[@class="select-swatch clearfix"]/div/div[1]/label::div/div[1]/label''')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this is the data you are trying to extarct.

```
driver.get("https://moho.com.vn/products/bo-ban-an-go-cao-su-tu-nhien-moho-vline-601")

# Get the Colors available
colors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='variant-swatch-0']//label")
data = []

# Iterate over the colors
for color in colors:
    color.click()
    
    # Get all the 6 options for that color
    options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-option='option2']/div[2]/div")

    # Iterate over the options to extract respective sku and price.
    for option in options:
        option.click()
        sku = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@id='pro_sku']").get_attribute("innerText")
        price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='pro-price']").get_attribute("innerText")
        print(f"{color.text}: {option.text} - {sku} - {price}")
```

```
Màu Tự Nhiên: 4 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Màu Tự Nhiên: 1 Ghế Băng Dài + 2 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Màu Tự Nhiên: 1 Ghế Băng Tựa + 2 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Màu Tự Nhiên: 2 Ghế Băng Tựa - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Màu Tự Nhiên: 2 Ghế Băng Dài - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Màu Tự Nhiên: 1 Ghế Băng Dài + 1 Ghế Băng Tựa - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 4 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 1 Ghế Băng Dài + 2 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 1 Ghế Băng Tựa + 2 Ghế Đơn - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 2 Ghế Băng Tựa - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 2 Ghế Băng Dài - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
Nâu: 1 Ghế Băng Dài + 1 Ghế Băng Tựa - SKU:MFDTSVLDC4.N16 - 7,390,000₫
```

Comment: I wonder how you find the HIDED xpath ("//div[@data-option='option2']/div[2]/div".  Finding the xpath to get elements, I always use  R-click Inspect option on the website. Please teach me.

Comment: @astonle - After Inspect built the xpath for the element. [Link to refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/).